# Why wont this for loop let me use a count?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, matplotlib, indexing

So what im trying to do is have the code run through each element in the list 'data' which has values in it from another file, and start from the second element in the list. So i used a for loop with an index, i, and used data[i+1] which works usually. However i am getting an error when running.

*C = data[i+1]
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str*

It seems as though it does not like me doing 'i+1' but i dont understand why.

The relevant code is below, i've only included the relevant parts of the function. Thanks for any help!

Edit: What im trying to do is have the code loop through each item in the list 'data',where data is a list of values, im trying to make C equal to the value of the item in the 'i+1'th position. Is my use of a for loop incorrect here?

```
def correctFile(input,output):
    r = open(input + ".txt","r")
    w = open(output + ".txt","w")
    for l in r:
        line = []
        data = l.split("   ")
        yearmonth = data[0]
        datelist = yearmonth.split("/")
        for i in data:
            C = data[i+1]
            clean = C.lstrip(" ")
            line.append(str(clean))
```

Comment: Read the error message: Because "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str". `i` is a string.

Comment: `i` is a sting, namely a part of the `data`. So suppose `data` is `"Hello, I'm a line"`, then, `i` might be `"Hello,"` and then python is confused how to add `1` to `"Hello,"`.

Comment: What i want it to do is run through each element in the list, and start from the 'i+1'th position. and each element in the list is a number, it isnt a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your for loop to something like this:

```py
for i in range(len(data)):
```

Answer (score 0):

i is a string

say data[0] is "word" then i will be "word" not 0

to make i an integer, just do something like this

```
for i in range(len(data)):
  C = data[i+1]
```

Comment: I try this and i get an error, 'list index out of range". What im trying to do is have the code loop through each item in the list 'data', and i was trying to make C equal to the value of the item in the 'i+1'th position.

Comment: you can just use data[i] instead of data[i+1] if you want to loop through the entire thing